# Auto-focus feature for tag-it

Tags: jquery-ui, list, menu, autofocus

In the plugin tag-it from https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it (demo - http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/examples.html), how is it possible to add the autofocus (i.e If set to true the first item will automatically be focused when the menu is shown) feature in the jquery - tag-it.js?

EDIT: The feature should also enable the suggestion to be inputted or made appear in the input box when 'Enter key' is hit.

Comment: Do you mean the first available suggestion is shown and selected using the "Single Input Field" example?

Comment: Yes I mean the first available suggestion should be highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem of entering the auto-focused suggestion by making some of the following in the tag-it.js file:

Defined a variable for receiving the value of focused suggestion on line 113 just after `var that = this;`:

```
var that = this;
var focuse;
```

On or after line 279 and function - `this.tagInput.keydown(function(event) {})`, the following has to be added:

```
.on( "autocompletefocus", function( event, ui ) {

focuse = ui.item.value;

})
```

Then finally within the function `this.tagInput.keydown(function(event) {})`, replace `that.createTag(that._cleanedInput());` with:

```
if (focuse !== '' && event.which === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER)
{
that.createTag(focuse);
focuse = '';
}
else
{
that.createTag(that._cleanedInput());
}
```

To enable to autofocus, add the autocomplete (`autocomplete: {autoFocus: true}`) option in the file that calls the tagit plugin as:

```
$("#tags").tagit({
availableTags : availableTags,
autocomplete: {autoFocus: true}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/8/

I hope that is what you are expecting

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];

$("#tags").tagit({
    availableTags : availableTags,
    showAutocompleteOnFocus : true,
    autocomplete: {delay: 0, minLength: 0, autoFocus: true},
});
});
```